# R: Error while installing RJson file

Tags: json, r

I am trying to install json package in R from cran repository. I am getting a compilation failure issue.

```
Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3PA/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3PA/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="rjson.dll" OBJECTS="dump.o parser.o"' had status 127

ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rjson'
* removing 'C:/Users/30295/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/rjson'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3PA/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\30295\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" "D:/BIGDAT~1/SWARNA~1/rjson_0.2.15.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘D:/BIGDAT~1/SWARNA~1/rjson_0.2.15.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Can someone please help me what could be the reason for this?

Comment: Please post the complete console output.

Comment: while this doesn't solve your issue, have you considered the [`jsonlite`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html) package - I find it easier to use / better than `rjson`?